# High to low poly count

Tags: export, collada

I am trying to display a model from Blender in SceneKit. Exporting with .DAE (`COLLADA`). However, the CPU goes up to 100%+. The model is 122MB so i tried to lower the poly count. In Blender i lowered vertices from 20k to 5k. See below:
[image: Blender stats]

But when I load the model in SceneKit the poly count is still the same. I also tried converting the model and the animations to .SCN instead. This resulted in much **lower** file size, however the **same** poly count and CPU usage.
[Pictures of showStatistics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkqZY.jpg)

The poly count is about 68k, both when vertices is around 20k and 5k. How do I lower the poly count?

Comment: Yes, I am using the decimate modifier. And I actually didn't press Apply. When I do, I get an error saying "Modifier cannot be applied to a mesh with shape keys".

Comment: When you export to Collada, in the lower left corner there are options and there is an Apply Modifiers checkbox, so you do not have to actually apply them in the scene, and shape keys will not be a problem.

Comment: Thanks Róbert! Should I select View or Render?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the decimate modifier, make sure you **Apply** the modifier to make the change real.